# Replacing the missing values in python with Lists in python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, merge, missing-data

I have a dataframe and wanted to fill the Nan values of particular column with the list derived from other calculation.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1,Nan,3,Nan], columns=['A'])
values_to_be_filled = [100.942,90.942]


df
     A
0    1
1    Nan
2    3
3  Nan



output: 

df2 
      A
 0    1
 1    100.942
 2    3
 3    90.942
```

I have tried use the replace function but not able to replace with the list elements. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: What happens if the DF has 3 nan's?

Comment: if there are 3 nan's then there would be 3 elements in the list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df.loc[df["A"].isnull(), "A"] = values_to_be_filled
```